# Installing Command-T breaks MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugins

I am trying to install [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) on [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim). I followed the installation instructions *exactly* but I get this error when trying to start MacVim (from a terminal via the `mvim` command line utility).

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /Users/mark/.vim/ruby/command-t/ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /Users/mark/.vim/ruby/command-t/ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Vim: Caught deadly signal TRAP
Vim: Finished.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to compile Command-T with Ruby v 1.8.7. Use RVM to switch between ruby versions. After you compiled the source you may switch back to your other ruby version.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this when I get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, installed 1.8.7 with rbenv, deleted ~/.vim/ruby/command-t and re-sourced the vimball, use 1.8.7 to `ruby extconf.rb` and then things worked great.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I compiled Command-T with a MacPorts ruby version (`/opt/local/bin/ruby`).

When I recompiled with `/usr/bin/ruby`, the version that is shipped with OS X, the issue was resolved and everything worked fine.