# MacVim, Command-T: SEGV

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugins

Details:

- OSX 10.7.4

I installed the latest MacVim via Homebrew:

```
$ command-t  brew install macvim
==> Downloading https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/tarball/snapshot-64
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/macvim-7.3-64.tgz
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --with-tlib=ncurses --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-t
==> make getenvy
==> make
==> Caveats
MacVim.app installed to:
  /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64

To link the application to a normal Mac OS X location:
    brew linkapps
or:
    ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64/MacVim.app /Applications
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64: 1733 files, 27M, built in 53 seconds
$  command-t  brew linkapps
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64/MacVim.app
Finished linking. Find the links under ~/Applications.
$  command-t  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0]
$  command-t  rvm list

rvm rubies

   ree-1.8.7-2012.02 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p358 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$  command-t  cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-command-t/ruby/command-t
ruby extconf.rb
$  command-t  ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby.h... yes
creating Makefile
$  command-t  make
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o ext.bundle ext.o match.o matcher.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
ld: warning: ignoring file ext.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file match.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file matcher.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
$  command-t  mvim
```

MacVim then opens here. But when I open Command-T, MacVim crashes and I see this in the command line:

```
$  command-t  dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /Users/ramon/.vim/bundle/vim-command-t/ruby/command-t/ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /Users/ramon/.vim/bundle/vim-command-t/ruby/command-t/ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Vim: Caught deadly signal TRAP
Vim: Finished.
```

The problem I have is very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/247678/installing-command-t-breaks-macvim), except that I switched to the system Ruby and still got the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

towards the end of your install/configure, it looks like three object files are ignored due to a architecture mismatch.

```
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o ext.bundle ext.o match.o matcher.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
ld: warning: ignoring file ext.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file match.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file matcher.o, file was built for unsupported file
```

Is it possible those files were there previously, maybe not built by your system, but carried along by the archive bundle in some manner?

Perhaps a removal of the object files (make clean?) and a rebuild might help?

Definitely something though, as your lazy-link failure shows your system can't find something... perhaps it's those object files.

Comment: Ugh.. I uninstalled everything and installed it several times, and it still happened. But I tried it again this one time, exactly the same way, then it worked! Maybe one of the packages was updated? So I don't know for sure what the problem was, but yours sounds pretty good.